# English ‘firm’ vs. German ‘Firma’ with respect to prepositional collocations?

Tags: difference, preposition, meaning-in-context, phrase

According to Oxford English Dictionary, a ***firm*** is

> a business concern, especially one involving a **partnership** of two or more people

Hence, a distinction in collocation with preposition is made according to that, for example, between:

> an **employee** **of** a firm
>
> a **partner** **in** a firm

the difference in choice of preposition reflects the difference in meaning: An employee has nothing to do with the ownership of the firm, while a partner does.

I am wondering whether the German term ***Firma*** has the same shade of meaning as its English counterpart *firm:* Does *Firma* refer to such a type of business as involves partnership?

This question arises when I try to discern the nuances between the following:

> bei einer Firma arbeiten
>
> in einer Firma arbeiten

I am wondering whether the nuance between the two may be attributed to the semantic element *partnership,* which is possibly encoded in the term *Firma.*

Answer (score 11):

*Firm* in English means the relationship to ownership, the legal entity - It roughly translates to, for example, the German "Gesellschaft" or "Firmierung".

"Firma" in German initially meant the same thing about a hundred years ago, but has evolved into a wider meaning over time - It loosely translates to *company* or *enterprise*. (Note, Austrian German and German legalese in general, seems to be slightly different here, see Hubert's answer and comments there)

Both *Firma* and *firm* stem from the same Latin verb "firmare", meaning "confirm by signage" - The German meaning has more generalized over time than the English.

With regards to prepositions:

1. German doesn't actually *need* a preposition to connotate "something belongs to something else" - We would normally express this with the genitive case:

   > Der Angestellte einer Firma, der Geschäftsführer einer Firma, der (Mit-)eigentümer einer Firma

   Generally, the German genitive would translate to the English preposition "of". Obviously, there is no distinction between just working there or owning it ("having signed for it"). You need to derive this from the substantive.
2. In case you want to use a preposition, both "bei" and "in" would mean the same thing, not further specifying wether someone is just working there or participating in a partnership.

And just some more trivia you didn't ask for: You might find the abbreviation *ppa* on business cards or e-mail signatures as part of a job title. This stands for *per procura auctoritate* and means someone is fully entitled for signage *on behalf of the firm*.

Answer (score 7):

### Firma

I don't know much about the English term »firm«, but I do know exactly what »Firma« means in Austria, and I guess it is the same as in Germany. (»Firma« is a juristic term, and because of Germany and Austria having their own specific laws, you have to read the laws of both countries to make sure if the same term really means the same thing.)

A »*Firma*« is (at least in Austria) just the name of a registered enterprise. It is not the company itself, but just its name. All such registrations are collected in the »*Firmenbuch*«. This is not a real book (maybe it was a real book a long time ago), but a database at the »*Handelsgericht*« (*commercial court*). So a *Firma* is nothing, that an enterprise can *be*, but it is something, that an enterprise can *have*.

But there are also fully legal enterprises that are not registered in the *Firmenbuch*. Such an enterprise has no *Firma*, i.e. is has no registered name. This is possible, if the sales of an enterprise are lower than one million euro per year and if it is owned by only one person. In this case, the name of that enterprise used on documents (on bills or shop signs for example) must contain the surname and the first name of the owner of that enterprise (for example: »Hans Müller Wurstwaren«, »Café Lisa Stein« or »Änderungsschneiderei Irene Bayer«).

An enterprise, that has no *Firma*, can have employees, and they can have more than one branch. They just have to keep their sales below 1 million euro per year.

There are even companies (enterprises with two or more owners) that are not registered in the *Firmenbuch* and therefore have no *Firma* (»*Gesellschaft bürgerlichen Rechts*« = *company of civil law*). These companies per definition have partners, and they also can have employees.

In colloquial talk you often can hear sentences like this:

> Ich arbeite seit Februar bei einer neuen Firma, sie heißt »Blaue Orange«.
>   Gerda hat gestern einen Tisch bei der Firma Gerwisch gekauft.
>   Mir reicht es jetzt, ich werde meinen Vertrag mit der Firma Sauber-Wisch kündigen!
>   Herr Fink ist jetzt auch Partner der Firma Schlössler.

But juridically it is wrong to talk about a *Firma* in these cases because the *Firma* is not the company or enterprise, but just it's registered name. But there are other terms (like *Unternehmen*, see next section), that can be used instead, and their usage is also correct in a juridical manner.

So, theoretically, you should replace »Firma« by »Unternehmen« in all examples above, but nobody does. When "normal" people (others than jurists) talk with each other, they use the term »Firma« not for the name of the enterprise, but for the enterprise itself. So, for non-jurists, it is absolutely ok to uses the sentences quoted above.

**about prepositions**

> 1. Ich arbeite *bei* der Firma Hellwig & Co.
> 2. Ich arbeite *in* der Firma Hellwig & Co.

Both versions are correct and usual. But for my personal flavour I would prefer #1 (*bei*), because *in* has a connotation of »being inside the companies building« while *bei* has more the meaning of »being a member of the team«. But as just said: This is my personal point of view, maybe other people have other opinions.

> 1. Ich bin Partner **bei** der Firma Hellwig & Co.
> 2. Ich bin Partner **in** der Firma Hellwig & Co.
> 3. Ich bin Partner der Firma Hellwig & Co.

Here I would prefer the version without preposition (3) (in English: *being partner **of** that enterprise*) over #1 (*bei*) (*being partner **at** that enterprise*), and this again over #2 (*in*) (*being partner **in** that enterprise*).

---

### Unternehmen

This is an enterprise. In its smallest form a *Unternehmen* has just one owner, no partners and no employees.

Take my own enterprise as an example: I produce websites and do other IT-related jobs. To be allowed to do this, I needed to register a *Gewerbe* (*business*), and now I am the owner of an *Unternehmen* (*enterprise*). I have no partners and no employees. I didn't have to register a *Firma*, but I did voluntarily. The *Firma* of my *Unternehmen* is »SHAPP - Schölnast Hubert Applications e.U.« (»*e.U.*« stands for »eingetragenes Unternehmen« = *registered enterprise*)

But an enterprise can have any size. It can have any number of partners and any number of employees. The biggest *Unternehmen* in Austria is a Bank: »[Erste Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erste_Group)«, maybe the best known Austrian *Unternehmen* is [Red Bull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Bull_GmbH).

---

### Gesellschaft

This is a company, and *Gesellschaften* are a subset of *Unternehmen* (every *Gesellschaft* is an *Unternehmen*, but there are *Unternehmen* that are not a *Gesellschaft*).

A *Gesellschaft* has at least two owners (*Unternehmen* doesn't have this restriction), and the term *Gesellschaft* is the umbrella term for a bundle of different kinds of how a *Gesellschaft* can juridically be realised:

- Gesellschaft mit beschränkter Haftung (GmbH)
- Aktiengesellschaft (AG)
- Offene Gesellschaft (OG)
- Kommanditgesellschaft (KG)
- Gesellschaft bürgerlichen Rechts (GesbR)
- Stille Gesellschaft (stG)
- Erwerbs- und Wirtschaftsgenossenschaft (Gen)

I think Germany has similar types of *Gesellschaften*. (Sorry, I don't want to describe them in detail.)

But beside this commercial *Gesellschaften*, there are also non-commercial groups that can have employees:

---

### Verein

This is an association. In Germany it is called »eingetragener Verein« (*registered association*), in Austria just »Verein«. Almost all sports clubs and most cultural clubs are not registered as an *Unternehmen* but as a *Verein*. Also, motor clubs like ÖAMTC and ARBÖ in Austria or ADAC in Germany are no *Unternehmen*. They are *Vereine* with thousands of employees and hundreds of branches.

---

### Addendum

What I've said about *Firma* in Austrian laws seems to be true also for German laws. Also in Germany a »Firma« is in the written laws not an enterprise, but just it's name.

Quote from German *Handelsgesetzbuch*:

> § 17 (1) Die Firma eines Kaufmanns ist der Name, unter dem er seine Geschäfte betreibt und die Unterschrift abgibt.
>
> *(My translation: The "Firma" of a merchant is the name under which he operates his business and that he uses as signature.)*

But as said above: In colloquial speech you use the word *Firma* also in Germany as if it would mean »enterprise«.

Comment: +1, but only *Kapitalgesellschaften* have to be registered at the Handelsgericht, because they are legal entities of their own. Owner-run companies and *Personengesellschaften* don't have to, because the owners are the legal entities.

Comment: There is even the colloquial meaning of "Firma" as referring to a company building or site - "bring die Sachen mal zur Firma XY", "habe die Schlüssel in der Firma vergessen"...

Comment: @Janka: I didn't want to drill too deep into details. This board is about German language, not about Austrian laws.

Comment: Cannot say for Austria, but I pretty much doubt "Firma" shows up in any legal text or law. It definitely doesn't in German laws. Way to colloquial and unspecific.

Comment: Austrian German actually seems to have retained much more of the original meaning of "Firma" than in Germany and thus seems to be much closer to the English *firm*. Interesting and +1!

Comment: @tofro: Der Begriff »Firma« taucht in fast allen österreichischen Gesetzen auf. Z.B. im Firmenbuchgesetz, im Unternehmensgesetzbuch, in der Gewerbeordnung, im Rückstellungsgesetz, GmbH-Gesetz, Sprengmittelgesetz, Aktiengesetz, Schaumweinsteuergesetz, Biersteuergesetz, Tabaksteuergesetz, Düngemittelgesetz, Futtermittelgesetz, Mineralölsteuergesetz, Erwerbsgesellschaftengesetz, Bankwesengesetz, Kartellgesetz usw. Das RIS (Rechtsinformationssystem) des ö. Bundeskanzleramtes spuckt allein bei den Bundesgesetzen 2243 Treffer für »Firma« aus. Es fällt mir schwer zu glauben, dass das in D anders ist.

Comment: Es ist so. Im Bürgerlichen Gesetzbuch (BGB, online zugänglich), das z.B. hauptsächlich für "Handel und Wandel" zuständig ist, taucht der Begriff *Firma* nicht ein einziges Mal auf. Dort wird von *Unternehmen*, *juristischen Personen*, *Gesellschaften* und *Gesellschaftsformen* gesprochen. "Firma" wird im deutschen Hochdeutsch als umgangssprachliches Synonym dafür verwendet.

Comment: @tofro: Ich gehe davon aus, das die österreichische Entsprechung dieses Gesetzes das AGBG ist (Langtitel: »Allgemeines bürgerliches Gesetzbuch für die gesammten deutschen Erbländer der Oesterreichischen Monarchie«). In der aktuell gültigen Fassung kommt dort das Wort »Firma« auch nur ein einziges Mal vor, nämlich im § 1028: »*Die Rechte solcher Geschäftsführer sind vorzüglich aus der Urkunde ihrer Bestellung, dergleichen unter Handelsleuten das ordentlich kundgemachte Befugniß der Unterzeichnung (**Firma**) ist, zu beurtheilen.*«

Comment: @tofro: Ich habe zwar keine offizielle Seite gefunden, auf der man auf deutsche Gesetzestexte zugreifen kann, aber dejure.org scheint zumindest die wichtigsten zu enthalten. Der Begriff »Firma« liefert immerhin 163 Treffer: https://dejure.org/cgi-bin/suche?Suchenach=Firma Aber wie gesagt: Ich habe keine Ahnung, wer dejure.org betreibt, und wie zuverlässig bzw. vollständig die hinterlegten Gesetzestexte sind. Das österreichische RIS https://www.ris.bka.gv.at ist hingegen eine offizielle Regierungsseite. Der Betreiber der Seite ist also der Verfasser der Gesetze selbst.

Comment: Das BGB gibt es beim Verfasser (dem deutschen Bundesjustizministerium) hier im Volltext: https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/BJNR001950896.html

Comment: Das deutsche BGB ist, wie das österreischische ABGB, das falsche Gesetz um nach »Firma« zu suchen. Da geht es ja um *bürgerliches* Recht, nicht um Wirtschaftsrecht. Aber schau mal, was ich gefunden habe: https://dejure.org/gesetze/HGB/17.html oder hier: https://dejure.org/gesetze/BeurkG/41.html

Comment: Juristendeutsch scheint den Begriff wirklich noch so zu verwenden.

Answer (score 1):

Firma, at least in typical modern usage, translates well to the English word Company - it's used quite freely to refer to any business of decent size.

In my experience, there is no real connotative difference between "bei einer Firma" or "in einer Firma", however I have seen "bei" used much more frequently. That being said, both imply some high level of involvement in a company. A CEO "arbeitet bei" a company, but an entry level worker "arbeiter für" a company. I found this analogous to the way you would say that a worker is employed by a company, but would not be likely to use this phrasing for an executive.